# Will this Cherry tomato sprout ever grow its first leaves?

Tags: tomatoes, germination, seedlings

I have planted three cherry tomato seeds. One has sprouted among them, but for the past two days its leaves are not emerging from the seeds. It’s the same as shown in the picture below.

I'm also wondering if that seed shell is too hard or something.

[image: Cherry Tomato]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Stuck Leaves Sometimes the cotyledons (the first leaves formed from the seed) have trouble getting loose from the seed coating. Be patient, as the leaves will usually escape. You could wet the seed coating, or you could try to carefully pinch off the seed coat, but if you pinch off the cotyledons, the seedling will likely die. A simple way to wet the seedlings is with a spray bottle of water set to mist. A small drop of saliva is also very effective at loosening seedcoats.

https://faq.gardenweb.com/discussions/2766771/how-do-i-start-tomatoes-from-seed